# How can I find a job in industry that matches my profile?

Tags: career-development, career-switch, careers

Currently, I am doing a postdoc and I would like to move onto industry. I did not network in the past and paid attention to a possible career in industry and now that I have made a decision, I feel I cannot find a job that might match my profile.

- **During my graduate and undergraduate studies of physics:**

  1. I studied math-intensive courses. So I feel competent about math problems. Even if I do not know the subject, I can learn it on my own.
  2. Solved differential equations using Mathematica or Matlab to study physics-based problems.
- **During my PhD in biophysics:**

  1. I performed fluorescence microscopy and spectroscopy. I did not maintain the equipment. I learned to operate them and know how they work in general.
  2. Analyzed the experimental data with Mathematica and Matlab and to a lesser degree with Python.
  3. I published four papers. They are mainly about energy transfer in photosynthetic organisms.
- **During my postdoc:**

  1. I performed bright field and fluorescence microscopy.
  2. I learned molecular biology techniques such as PCR, yeast and bacterial transformation (sometimes using CRISPR/Cas9).
  3. I analyzed my experimental data in Python.
  4. Hopefully, I will publish one or two papers. They will be mainly about a network of interacting proteins in yeast which help one important protein to localize on the cell membrane.
- **Overall:**

  1. I learned to devise a research project and plan the required experiments.
  2. Organize my data and workflow.
  3. I learned about molecular biology.
  4. While, I did not publish anything directly on mathematical modeling, I feel competent to do so if it is required, at least as long as the model involves ordinary differential equations.
  5. I supervised master students and was involved in demonstrating groups of students the experimental procedure of fluorescence spectroscopy.

I am interested to work in industry in the area of molecular biology, however, since my PhD was not biology related I feel I might not be as knowledgeable as a PhD graduate in biology or molecular biology. I think because I changed my research field during my master, PhD, and postdoc I might not have the depth of knowledge of a person who did biology since their master. None the less, I am not afraid to learn, but I do not know how much time and opportunity industry entry level positions provide the employee with to learn or if it allows it at all.
I hope if I cannot find a job in molecular biology area, at least I can find a job that matches my profile, however, I need a bit of help to find the proper sector.

1. What advice do you have for me in terms of the possible sectors of R&D which matches my profile?
2. Do you think the recruiter would be interested with my profile in the molecular biology R&D as compared to someone who studied the subject since their master?

Comment: Have you applied to any related/interesting jobs that you see and like? Sometimes that is better than not applying and speculating "oh, I can't find a job that's a good fit for me"...

Comment: @DarkCygnus I have not applied yet. I still have 9 months left for my current position. I plan to search for jobs in industry during next 3 months to see what I might like and could succeed. Six months before the end of my contract I plan to start applying for jobs.

Answer (score 1):

> What advice do you have for me in terms of the possible sectors of R&D which matches my profile?

As Joe suggested in comments, it would greatly help you to talk and get advice from the job placement office, coaching/counseling, or similar department, from your university. They are more than ideal to answer these and several questions you may have regarding finding a job that's a good fit for your profile.

> Do you think the recruiter would be interested with my profile in the molecular biology R&D as compared to someone who studied the subject since their master?

This is hard to answer, as it would depend on each recruiter and their needs and point of view, as well as the complete profile and career of the person to compare you to.

However, I am quite positive that having a candidate that has a a PhD in Biophysics and a Post Doc on Molecular Biology who has published papers, would definitely be interesting for a job that requires that knowledge.